# Image won't align at top of div - see example

Tags: html, css

I cannot figure out how to make all my images align at the top instead of centred like they are. If you look [here](http://www.northerntechnomics.com/lmantzel/googlemap/maptest12.html) the images with larger captions align at the top and it looks silly since they don't all line up. I was wondering if someone could help me figure out why. Here is the CSS for the DIV that contains the images:

```
thumbnail {
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 125px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: normal;
}

img{
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: `.thumbnail { ... vertical-align:top; }` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try adding `vertical-align: top;` to your thumbnail ?

Comment: It would be nice if you explained the answer instead of posting it in a question to the OP. Your answer was flagged as low quality which is why I am suggesting you to improve it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `vertical-align: top;` In your thumbnail div.

Answer (score 2):

vertical-align:top; on the thumbnail class should fix this.